# image colors different from windows photo viewer to other programs

Tags: color, color-profile, calibration

I have a jpg I output from Illustrator.  When I view the jpg in Photoshop or a browser, the colors are consistent, but when I view the same jpg in Windows photo viewer, the colors are much darker.  I think it might be a color profile issue, but I'm not sure.  For what it's worth, I recently began using ColorMunki to calibrate my monitor, and this hadn't been an issue prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Photoviewer is profile aware, but for example Irfanview is not (only internally).

Change profile to sRGB.

Comment: PS. Thunderbird is also NOT profile aware.